# How to change position create new option in select.creatable with reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I want put "create new" option to bottom option list in selectbox. Could I change position this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that latest version of react-select.js

```
createOptionPositionunion = "last"
```

Sets the position of the createOption element in your options list. Defaults to 'last'

One of <
"first",
"last"
>

Answer (score 0):

createOptionPosition="first"

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.